# Specific css selectors being overriden by non-specific

Tags: css, sass

I have some very specific selectors that are being overridden by very generic styles. Chrome and FF show the same style (the wrong, generic, one), but their devtools show something slightly different, neither of which makes any sense to me. Here are screenshots of the specificity of the elements, can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

The proper, most specific selector SHOULD be 24px

**Note:** There are NO !important used. I am using sass in the backend of this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are sure that your element matches this selector? Markup and CSS will help.

Comment: It looks like the latest version of app.css is 15179 to which it is set font-size to `inherit`. The version that sets font-size to 24px is version 13541.

Comment: So @smilebomb was correct in the element matching the selector (sorry I can't post the elements, lots of junk in there). By moving the .sub-field-highlights selector to the DIRECT parent element, rather than the grand-grand-parent selector, it applied correctly. I'm still unsure as to why this was necessary as it never is as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the order of the file. Browser applies rules from top to bottom, so put generic selectors to top of the file and specific selectors to the bottom.

Comment: Files are read top down, but if rules were applied in the same way there would be no point to specificity. Specific rules at the top of a file will overrule general rules at the bottom.

Comment: @smilebomb no it works in favor of declarations that are the lowest.

Comment: @zer00ne We must be talking about different things... the rules applied by the browser are the ones that are most specific, regardless of position in the file. In this fiddle, a 'lower' rule is clearly not applied because of a rule with a higher specificity. https://jsfiddle.net/oth2pr76/